# Why is my kernel choosing disk swap over 24G of inactive RAM?

Tags: linux, swap

Output below is `meminfo` from a Proxmox hypervisor. I noticed today that swap usage was 90%. I logged into the box and checked and and it seems there is actually 24G of inactive RAM. A couple minutes later, I noticed swap usage was at 99%. 
[image]

Why does the kernel appear to be favoring disk swap when there is so much inactive RAM available (EDIT: added `vmstat -s` below)?

```
# cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       131911836 kB
MemFree:        28128112 kB
MemAvailable:   51794976 kB
Buffers:          397876 kB
Cached:         23298352 kB
SwapCached:       509796 kB
Active:         73136224 kB
Inactive:       24833836 kB
Active(anon):   72432368 kB
Inactive(anon):  2030612 kB
Active(file):     703856 kB
Inactive(file): 22803224 kB
Unevictable:       20256 kB
Mlocked:           20260 kB
SwapTotal:       8388604 kB
SwapFree:          76592 kB
Dirty:               216 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      73881564 kB
Mapped:           196212 kB
Shmem:            182376 kB
Slab:            3837772 kB
SReclaimable:    1413588 kB
SUnreclaim:      2424184 kB
KernelStack:       10608 kB
PageTables:       281164 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    74344520 kB
Committed_AS:   265844288 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   2787328 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     3584964 kB
DirectMap2M:    118982656 kB
DirectMap1G:    13631488 kB
```

`vmstat -s`

```
    131911840 K total memory
     85913712 K used memory
     80380944 K active memory
     24732132 K inactive memory
     20989356 K free memory
       405840 K buffer memory
     24602928 K swap cache
      8388604 K total swap
      8311256 K used swap
        77348 K free swap
     62711183 non-nice user cpu ticks
       711584 nice user cpu ticks
     19418784 system cpu ticks
   2202190185 idle cpu ticks
     12801599 IO-wait cpu ticks
            0 IRQ cpu ticks
       583222 softirq cpu ticks
            0 stolen cpu ticks
  11537252613 pages paged in
   3575771252 pages paged out
      1581238 pages swapped in
      3670384 pages swapped out
   3388189898 interrupts
   3739302263 CPU context switches
   1535799398 boot time
      3674458 forks
```

Comment: What is the value of kernel swappiness ?  `sysctl -a | grep vm.swappiness`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Was set to 60. Turning it down to 40. I'll run it a few days that way and see if things improve. Could be I just need to add RAM.

Comment: Was your system using memory earlier, requiring the temporary usage of swap?

Comment: We run dumps (with compression) of the virtual machines from 1am to 3am which may be causing a fair amount of memory pressure. I have graphs from `sysstat` output but it looks like swap is consistently full on a daily basis. Looking for a way to tell it to empty swap so I can see exactly when it starts filling up again but the dumps are suspect.